# How to handle an AttributeError(key) using a automap_base in Sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

Please, help how to solve this error -  AttributeError(key):

```
  File "pivot_table_measurements.py", line 1, in <module>
    from database import *
  File "/home/dedeco/Projetos/bigclima-project/database.py", line 24, in <module>
    MeasureRanges = Base.classes.measure_ranges
  File "/home/dedeco/craw/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 212, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(key)
AttributeError: measure_ranges
```

database.py:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm.exc import MultipleResultsFound, NoResultFound
import string
from decimal import Decimal

ECHO = False
AUTOFLUSH = False

Base = automap_base()

engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:pass@localhost:5432/clima', echo=ECHO)

Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)

Country = Base.classes.countries
State = Base.classes.states
City = Base.classes.cities
Measurement = Base.classes.measurements
MeasurementHourly = Base.classes.measurements_hourly
MeasureRanges = Base.classes.measure_ranges
Parameter = Base.classes.parameters
WeatherStation = Base.classes.weather_stations

session = Session(engine, autoflush=AUTOFLUSH)
```

The table measure_ranges exits on the database but I don't known why I'm receiving this error. When I delete this line ( MeasureRanges = Base.classes.measure_ranges) works, so I believe that error it's related with some issue in this table.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I decided to share this problem and the answer because it's a basic thing but can difficult to find the solution.

The problem happened because I don't create a **primary key** on this table, and because that it's not possible to automap to a class.

See the documentation:

> By viable, we mean that for a table to be mapped, it must specify a
>   primary key. Additionally, if the table is detected as being a pure
>   association table between two other tables, it will not be directly
>   mapped and will instead be configured as a many-to-many table between
>   the mappings for the two referring tables.

[See more details here: SQLAlchemy 1.2 Documentation - Autoamp](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html)